# Android::findViewByID - how can I get View of a TextView through a Listener of another UI element?

Tags: android

This is going to be a bit lame question. I have the following code:

```
..............
 public void onCreate (Bundle bundle)
 {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
  Button bnt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.browser);
  bnt.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());

 }
..............
class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{

 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
  // I have a TextView in my xml layout file. 
  // I'd like to get it and change my text when I click this button.
  // But I can't get it (the TextView) unless I make it as a value of a static member of this class and pass it to the constructor. 
  //I believe I am missing a big point here, so i'd be very thankful if you could explain how this is meant to be done ? 

 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try this:

```
class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View parent = (View)v.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            TextView txtView = parent.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
            txtView.setText(...);
        }
    }
}
```

the usage depends on your layout. Its possible, that the parent of your button is not the parent of your textview so be careful...

Comment: My point exactly. View parent = (View) v.getParent() - I wrote it this way though - .getParent() returns a ViewParent object. Still, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: the more robust way would be to give your root layout element an id and do a `findViewById()` in your `onCreate()`. So you have full easy access to your layout and all views inside. So Rahul has given the correct answer... just use the root element instead of the textview

Answer (score 8):

```
class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       View p = (View) view.getRootView();        
        if (p != null) {
            TextView txtView = (TextView) p.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
            txtView.setText(...);
        }
    }
}
```

*I need to set visible an element from the same parent so I used this code :) and it worked*

Comment: This worked for a view in a dialog, while using getParent() didn't.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I dont think it will be possible. The view V only has the buttons view in it....

You will know if you typecast the same

```
  class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
    {

     public void onClick(View v) 
     {

        Button vg=(Button)v;
        Log.e("", "views are "+vg.getText());
```

//However u can set the test here for ue textview 
txt.setText("change text");

```
     }
    }
```

---

I did not understand your question properly. But if you just want to get the text out from ur TextView you can try like this

```
TextView txt;

public void onCreate (Bundle bundle)
 {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
  Button bnt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.browser);
  txt=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.urtextview);
  bnt.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());

 }
..............
class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{

 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
  // I have a TextView in my xml layout file. 
  // I'd like to get it and change my text when I click this button.
  // But I can't get it (the TextView) unless I make it as a value of a static member of this class and pass it to the constructor. 
  //I believe I am missing a big point here, so i'd be very thankful if you could explain how this is meant to be done ? 
//I think this should get u the string...
System.out.println("text is "+txt.getText().toString());

 }
}
```

Comment: See, I have a button, and when I click it, I'd like to change the text of a TextView. So my question is "Is there a way to do that when only coding in the onClick method ?"  I did say it would be a lame question ...

Imagine I only have the (View v) information and I'd like to interact with a UI element in the layout.

Can I get all the UI elements in a layout if I only have a reference to one of them?

Comment: In your case i don't think it would be possible. If you are getting a layouts view probably u can get the children from it in ur case it will be just a button. Check my updated post