# Could not get or set edittext value from separate OnClickListener class using android studio 3

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Using eclipse i was able to get edittext value from separate onclicklistener class, but after i transfer the same style of code to android studio 3 the edittext returns empty here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnGenerate;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the generate_btn actually works
    btnGenerate = findViewById(R.id.generate_btn);
    btnGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerGenerate());
   }
 }
```

And here is the OnClickListener class

```
public class OnClickListenerGenerate implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText second_digit;
private static  final String TAG = OnClickListenerGenerate.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
      final Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
     second_digit = formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.txtSecondDigit);

     //returns empty
     Log.d(TAG, ">>" + second_digit.getText().toString());
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this link [Android::findViewByID - how can I get View of a TextView through a Listener of another UI element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675238/androidfindviewbyid-how-can-i-get-view-of-a-textview-through-a-listener-of-a#) and now it's working.

```
class ButtonListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
public void onClick(View v) {
    View parent = (View)v.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        TextView txtView = parent.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        txtView.setText(...);
    }
  }
}
```